# Read (NOT SET) focus on an input in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, focus, state

Weird question that google hasn't helped with... how do I read if an input is focused in React?

What I'm wanting to do is hide the autocomplete div I've created if the input is not focused. Is there a way to do that?

As it is now, if you leave something in the text input and don't click on one of the autocomplete suggestions, the autocomplete div will stay there even after moving to search results and the detail page.

I already tried messing with how the div is displaying in the first place (it's rendering once the user starts typing which sets the options in a state array) by setting the array it pulls from to nothing on submit, but then it gives me the too many renders error.

Here's the form:

```
<form className="input-group mb-3" onSubmit={submit()}>
    <input
        type="text"
        className="form-control mr-sm-2"
        onChange={e => onSearch(e)}
        placeholder="Search to follow the money"
        value={searchedValue}
        />
    <Link to={`/searchresults/${selected}`} selected={selected}>
        <button
            type="submit"
            className="btn btn-light my-2 my-sm-0 shadow-sm"
            style={{
                height: "40px",
                borderRadius: "0px",
                MozBorderRadius: "0px",
                WebkitBorderRadius: "0px"
            }}
        >
        <img
                alt="search-icon"
                src={require("../../assets/its-a-bribe-search-punch-01.png")}
                style={{ width: "24px" }}
            />
        </button>
    </Link>
</form>
```

The autocomplete div is below the form like this:

```
<div className="container auto-complete-container">{renderSugs()}</div>
```

The onSubmit is currently just this:

```
const submit = () => {
        // setSuggestions([]);

    }
```

If I uncomment the setSuggestions it just gives me the too many renders error, even if the form hasn't been submitted yet?

This is my onSearch function:

```
    const onSearch = e => {
        setSearchedValue(e.target.value);
        const value = e.target.value;
        let suggestions = [];

        if (value.length) {
            suggestions = options.filter(option => {
                var name = option.name;
                // console.log("option", option)
                return name.toLowerCase().includes(searchedValue.toLowerCase());
            });
        }
        setSuggestions(suggestions);
    };
```

And to render the suggestions I have a function called renderSugs that maps through the suggestions and displays this for each:

```
<Link
    key={item.id + Math.random() * 100}
    to={`/politician/${item.id}`}
    style={{ textDecoration: "none", color: "black" }}
>
    <li
        onClick={() => {
             setSearchedValue(item.name);
             setSuggestions([]);
        }}
    >
        {item.name}
    </li>
</Link>
```

In the onClick there you'll see that I'm doing a setSuggestions, and it works here just fine. But when I try that same thing in the onSubmit it doesn't work???

**Help?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming it it a class based component (since you tagged the question `state`) you can do it like this.

Wrap the suggestions div in a condition like this

```
{this.state.showSuggestions && <div className="container auto-complete-container">{renderSugs()}</div>}
```

And add an `onFocus` and `onBlur` to your input

```
<input
    type="text"
    className="form-control mr-sm-2"
    onChange={e => onSearch(e)}
    placeholder="Search to follow the money"
    value={searchedValue}
    onFocus={() => this.setState({showSuggestions: true})}
    
    />

<Link
    key={item.id + Math.random() * 100}
    to={`/politician/${item.id}`}
    style={{ textDecoration: "none", color: "black" }}
    >
    <li
        onClick={ async () => {
            await setSearchedValue(item.name);
            await setSuggestions([]);
            this.setState({showSuggestions: false})}
        }}
    >
        {item.name}
    </li>
</Link>
```

Comment: So this worked, but now my Link tag isn't taking me to that page when I click on an autocomplete suggestion?

Comment: I checked and it isn't reading my click on a list item in the autocomplete div at all now...

Comment: It happens because when you click on the option it automatically blurs the input before it has a chance to navigate, So if you just want to navigate on click remove the `onBlur` from the input.

Comment: That worked, but the div isn't going away now like I wanted it to :( So basically I need that onBlur to make the div display change but if I have it I can't use my items in the autocomplete div as navigable items?

Comment: Add `this.setState({showSuggestions: false})}` to the link, see my updated answer. Hope that helps.

Comment: That doesn't seem to change anything... :( The way it is, the setSuggestions([]) is already doing the hiding of the div